# MySQL Select from two tables where userid in first row and item in second

Tags: mysql

i want to select informations from two tables.
In the first table i have the userid and the item_id

On the second table is saved the item_id and much infos about the item that i want.

But i want only to get the items where the userid is userid

I have tried that in javascript MySQL Query, but thats not very smart, to much requests and not a good way.

But i dont find a way to get the userid and get the item_id results from that user

```
pool.query('SELECT * FROM game_case, bank WHERE userid='+userid, function(err1, row1) {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM bank WHERE item_id='+row1[0].item_id, function(err2, row2) {
```

This gives me informations but very complicadet in for than to put in array and something

Comment: Please post your table structure, and maybe some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with inner join, you'll get your result according to your question

```
SELECT * FROM game_case inner join
bank on game_case.item_id=bank.item_id
WHERE userid='+userid
```

Comment: How do you know the column names of the `game_case` table?

Comment: op said he has two table, i don't know what columns are in game_case but item_id is there for sure